# what is the difference between obj=var and obj=fn

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

QUESTION: Is there a difference between assigning a function to a variable directly and assigning to a variable and then assigning the variable to another variable, as in the examples of vaFn and vaVar below?

I don't have any formal training, so I'm just wondering about the technical difference, if any of the items thissheet.vaFn and thissheet.vaVar?
This is Google Apps Script (javascript for Google Sheets)

```
function getSheet(shn) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(shn);
  var shrg = sh.getDataRange();
  var shrgva = shrg.getValues();

  var thissheet = {
    vaFn:shrg.getValues(),
    vaVar:shrgva
    };

  return thissheet;
}
```

Comment: `shrg` and `shrgdv` were not declared. What it's supposed that the code should do? Are you getting and error message?

Comment: There's no difference between them.

Comment: @Rubén - sorry. pasted wrong and didn't look.

Comment: `hissheet.dvFn` and `thissheet.dvVar` are not in the code. The title is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSheet(shn='Sheet0') {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(shn);
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const va = rg.getValues();
  let obj = {data:va};
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj.data));
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: what question are you answering?